# how to count number of click on google map marker in android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

How to get the number of click/tap on a marker in google maps.

```
@Override
public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker point) {
    Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, point.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Integer clickCount = (Integer) point.getTag();

    // Check if a click count was set, then display the click count.
    if (clickCount != null) {
        clickCount = clickCount + 1;
        point.setTag(clickCount);
        Toast.makeText(this, point.getTitle() + " has been clicked " + clickCount + " times.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost had it working:

```
@Override
public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker point) {
    Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, point.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Integer clickCount = (Integer) point.getTag();

    if (clickCount == null) {
        clickCount = 0;
    }

    clickCount = clickCount + 1;
    point.setTag(clickCount);
    Toast.makeText(this, point.getTitle() + " has been clicked " + clickCount + " times.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    return true;
}
```

Comment: only marker title from getTitle showing in first Toast, not the second Toast

Comment: I have tested my code and it's showing both `Toast`s and incrementing `clickCount`

Comment: Yeh it's working when I declare clickcount as int not Integer